# access airflow task arguments in the on_failure_callback function

Tags: python, airflow, rollback

I need a rollback operation to happen when a certain airflow task fails. To know what to rollback I need access to the task arguments inside the rollback function. The rollback function is passed to the `on_failure_callback` argument when defining the task.

Take this as a simplified example:

```py
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


def rollback(context: dict):
    print("How do I access the 'task_argument' value?")

@task(on_failure_callback=rollback)
def example_task(task_argument: str) -> None:
    assert False
    
@dag(
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
)
def example_dag() -> None:
    example_task("the task argument's value.")
    
example_dag()
```

How do I get the value that was passed to the `example_task` inside the `on_failure_callback`? I'm sure it's hiding in the `context` variable but I have not been able to find clear documentation on what is inside `context`. `context` does contain a field `params` but that does not contain `task_argument`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet worked for me..
Basically if you are using @task decorator you need to specify the context variable in the function arguments.
per this doc page
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/taskflow.html#taskflow

```html
from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


def rollback(context: dict):
    print("How do I access the 'task_argument' value?")
    print(context.get('params'))

@task(on_failure_callback=rollback)
def example_task(params: dict) -> None:
    assert False
    
@dag(
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
)
def example_dag() -> None:
    example_task(params={'mytask_param' : "the task argument's value."})
    
example_dag()
```