# How to dynamically modify Airflow task decorator attributes?

Tags: python, airflow

I want my extractor task to use a string variable to set the `pool`.

I realised I can do it like this:

```
@task(pool="my_pool")
def extractor_task(**kwargs):
```

But how can I do it dynamically, or how can I access those attributes and change them? Because I cannot dynamically change what I'm passing to the decorator, is there any other way to access the decorated extractor_task pool and set it as I want?

Comment: you can pass the pool as a runtime param to the DAG ,
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/params.html#dag-level-params
task level params pls see this answer ...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77906985/access-airflow-task-arguments-in-the-on-failure-callback-function/77907996#77907996
if you want it to be global scope you can use Airflow Variable
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77949387/how-can-i-dynamically-change-a-bucket-name-in-an-airflow-dag/77949461#77949461

Comment: @subram I tried it and it gives me the following error message `ValueError: cannot call partial) on task context variable params`.

 I am using the partial method of the task, like this `extractor_task.partial()`

Comment: the docs say "Only keyword arguments are allowed to be passed to partial()."
can you extract context["params"]["pool"] into a string and then pass it  as key=value to the partial call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the special `override()` method](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html#reusing-a-decorated-task) when using the TaskFlow API to set BaseOperator-level attributes like `pool`, `queue`, etc.

In your case to set `pool` dynamically, you could do:

```py
@task
def extractor_task(**kwargs):
    ...

pool_val = < some logic to set the variable value >

extract = extractor_task.override(pool=pool_val)(...)
```